# Remove a Layer using Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove a feature layer in an Arcpy Script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6148/how-can-i-remove-a-feature-layer-in-an-arcpy-script)

This question could seem too stupid, but i'm struggling with it, and it cannot work.

I have an mxd file containing raster layers, and I would like to remove a layer.  I don't know why it does not remove, it doesn't pop up any errors.  I'm trying this code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("photo.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for i in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd , "TerraColor_SanFrancisco_US_15m.tif"):
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df , i)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Any help please.